# How to suppress output in python without using characters and spaces?

Tags: python, io

I found out I can solve this problem in a better space complexity if I enter inputs one at time. However, python is defeating the purpose of my script.

Because python is outputting O(n) elements that I just gave for input.

```
0
2
no
```

See that 0 and 2 for inputs? I only need one line. *And it can only have the current input for that one particular line*. (**not 0,2....**) Otherwise, the computer is technically still using **O(n)** space just for the graphics card to remember what pixels to output.

I tried using os.devnull and other methods. But, the computer still used **O(N)** space by simply outputting *none* or *null*. Outputting space characters still use **O(N)** space so does every other possible character you can think of. Output must be 100% suppressed excluding the yes or no outputs.

This isn't impossible because I guarantee you that the algorithm works by hand with an auxiliary space better than **O(N)**

```
# Decision Problem: Is N in index M?
import sys
import os

M = 2
N = 2
index = -1
while True:

   # We are going to enter each element from our list ONE AT A TIME.
   # This will improve our space-complexity that is better than O(n)
   # Be careful not to enter the elements out of order.

   a = int(input(os.devnull))
   index = index + 1
   if a == N:
       if index == M:
           print('yes')
           break
   if index > M:
       print('no')
       break
   if index < M:
       if a == N:
           print('no')
           break
```

### Question

How do I suppress output completely without losing my "yes" or "no" outputs?

Comment: You realize you can print without the newline character, right?

Comment: @h0r53 How do I do that?

Comment: print("something", end="")

Comment: @h0r53 Printing something is not allowed. Because it would be using space. (except yes or no answers)

Comment: I don't mean print `something` literally. Replace that with what you desire to print. The point is Python3's `print` function has an optional keyword argument `end` which is used to delimit lines.

Comment: @h0r53 I tried that, but it used O(n) prints..